# openpyxl writes vlookup into excel file but excel file does not recognize the lookup variable

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I am desperate...and need your help.
I want to do a VLOOKUP via openpyxl in an excel file.
The setup:

- I got two sheets: sheet1 and sheet2.
- I am doing a lookup in sheet1 and looking for a match in sheet2 (table: mdexport).
- if I got a match I want to take a value of sheet2(mdexport) and write in in sheet1.

My script does the job partially:
The formula gets written in each cell correctly but inside the formula the lookup (cell) does not get recognized as cell by excel therefor the formula does not get evaluated. It looks like excel thinks this is just a regular string inside a cell.

If I want to get the formula working I need to go to in the address bar for each cell so excel recognize the lookup cell. Check the pictures for an example.

1. [formula after opening the excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnbCy.png)
2. [formula after clicking into the address bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzClw.png)

Does anybody know how to fix it?

```
import os
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_letter
 
wb = load_workbook(filename = f"{os.environ['USERPROFILE']}\\someFileName.xlsx")
 
ws0 = wb[wb.sheetnames[0]]
ws1 = wb[wb.sheetnames[1]]
 
def getColumnIndex(ColumnName, sheet):
    for cols in sheet.iter_cols(min_col = 1, max_col = ws1.max_column, max_row = 1):
        for val in cols:
            if val.value == ColumnName:
                return val.col_idx
 
col = getColumnIndex(ColumnName = 'columnNameToBeReplaced', sheet = ws1)
ws1.insert_cols(idx = col)
ws1.cell(row = 1, column = col, value = 'nameOfNewColumn')
colHost = get_column_letter(getColumnIndex(ColumnName = 'nameOfLookUpColumn', sheet = ws1))
for row in range(2, ws1.max_row + 1):
    ws1.cell(row = row, column = col).value = f'=VLOOKUP({colHost}{row}, md_export, 10, FALSE)'
```

Comment: I ran you code and it created the VLOOKUP() and calculations correctly. Ran it on windows. Don't think there is a problem with code. Try the code with new files (paste as text only) without copying format.

Comment: hm strange thing...maybe my excel settings are somewhat wrong?! i have automatic calculation activated though... what do you mean by 'Try the code with new files (paste as text only) without copying format.'?

Comment: Copy the data from existing file, paste it as text only in a new file and run the code on that new file. See if it runs fine. Would mean something funky in the existing excel...

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work at all. So I decided to write my own vlookup procedure with dictionaries. It is quite perfomant aswell. thanks anyways.